# VBA run time Error 3129 Illegal SQL-Statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to make a VBA Code to run a query when someone clicks on the button.

It always displays me the error in the title when I run it. Can someone help mes please? I'm thankful for every response.

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub btnNamebox_Click()

DoCmd.OpenForm "F-Smartphone-Hinzufuegen"
Dim strSQL As String
DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

strSQL = "SELECT Nachname" & _
"FROM tblPersonal " & _
"WHERE Handynummer = " & Forms![F-Smartphone-Hinzufuegen]![FKHandynummer] & ";"

txtnamebox.Value = strSQL

End Sub
```

Comment: There's no space between `SELECT Nachname` and `FROM tblPersonal`. Add a space after `SELECT Nachname `.

Comment: @MartinParkin that doesn't work. would be too easy

Comment: I'm not suggesting that's the answer, just something I noticed when looking at your question and it does need to be changed. `SELECT NachnameFROM tblPersonal` isn't valid SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code makes little sense - you run a SQL statement before you define it, and you can't `RunSQL` a SELECT statement anyways.

Use `DLookup()` instead:

```vb
S = Nz(DLookup("Nachname", _
        "tblPersonal", _
        "Handynummer = " & Forms![F-Smartphone-Hinzufuegen]![FKHandynummer]), "")
```